# Write function in C which count number of given integer digits, in 2 lines

Tags: c

Any suggestion for better solution?

In C:

```
int countDigits(int v) {
    for(int i=v, digits =1 ; i != 0; i = i/10,v = digits++);
    return v;
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with your code?

Comment: I can't use function arg. But this solution using variable v...

Comment: _I can't use function arg_. Why ??

Comment: How can you write a function to count the digits without using a function argument?

Comment: this `v = digits++` doesn't do what you think it does either

Answer (score 2):

If it is not allowed to introduce any variables, recursion might be an option:

```
int countDigits(int v) {
    return (v >= 10 || v <= -10 ? 1+countDigits(v/10) : 1);
}
```

Note the extra condition such that the function can also handle negative numbers correctly.

Comment: I suggest `return (v > 9 ? 1+countDigits(v/10) : 1);` so that it gives the correct result when passed `0`.

Comment: @Weather Vane: that was my first shot, too, but it does then not work for negative values. Adapted the code; should work now for `0` as well as for negative numbers.